# Consumo de Webservice roda apenas na depuração sob a IDE do Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, web-service, vb.net

Minha aplicação WinForms VB.NET consome um webservice para realizar algumas consultas. Quando executo em modo debug ou release sob a IDE do Visual Studio, funciona perfeitamente, mas uma vez distribuída nos computadores do cliente (or mesmo no meu próprio, rodando direto a partir do executável), ela falha com esta mensagem:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** Não foi possível localizar o elemento de ponto de extremidade padrão que referencia o contrato 'WsTrf3.IServicoIntegracao' na seção de configuração do ServiceModel cliente. Isso pode ter ocorrido devido à falta de um arquivo de configuração para o seu aplicativo ou porque nenhum elemento de ponto de extremidade correspondendo a este contrato pôde ser encontrado no elemento cliente.

Suponho que algo que está presente durante a depuração está faltando na distribuição, mas não faço ideia do quê. Qualquer ajuda será muito bem-vinda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente você está distribuindo seu aplicativo sem o arquivo de configuração (app.config) ou o arquivo de configuração do cliente não possui a chave ServiceModel. O correto seria, incluir estas configurações no arquivo de configuração da maquina do cliente.
Provavelmente esta seção existe dentro do arquivo app.config no seu projeto do visual studio e não existe no arquivo [nome_executável].exe.config na maquina do cliente.

Verifique mais sobre estas configurações na [documentação da Microsoft.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms733932(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

O amigo [Julio Borges](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/20712/julio-borges) me avisou de que eu deveria distribuir o arquivo **app.config** junto com o executável para resolver o problema. Isso está correto e portanto eu marcarei como resposta.

Mas ao lado disso, gostaria de alertar para uma outra solução que descobri, e que vou utilizar porque gostaria de manter a distribuição restrita a um único arquivo: é possível implantar os dados de configuração diretamente no código.

Assim, eu substituí:

```
Dim myclient as New MyServiceReference.MyServiceClient
```

por

```
Dim myclient as New MyServiceReference.MyServiceClient(
    New BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None),
    New EndpointAddress("http://myservice.mysite.com/services/MyService.svc?wsdl"))
```

E voilà, funcionou.

Muito obrigado a todos que tentaram me ajudar com isto!